# call webmethod from jquery ajax and problemm with static object

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

i have a webmethod that call it by jquery ajax .in web method i bind repeater data source to pagedatasourse object but when  i run my program if i dont use of static key word  webmethode before method name jquery ajax method dose not work properly and if use static keyword i have this error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object....System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and pagedatasourse fall in exception.i confused.what is solution?
thank you very much
 its my jquery function

```
 $(function () {
            var x = 0;
            $('.c1').bind('click', function () {

                counter = counter + 1;
                $.ajax(
                {
         type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm1.aspx/bringdata",
      data: { counter: counter },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           async: true,
            cache: false,
              success: function (ret) {

                alert("success");
           },
           error: function (x, e) {
           alert("error ");
                 }
                   }
                );

            })
            $('.c2').bind('click', function () {

                x = x - 1;

            })

        })
```

and its code behind :

```
  [WebMethod]
  public  static void bringdata(int counter){
   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.;database=site;integrated   security=true;");
   int cnt;
   string sSQL = "Select username ,average,weight,point,password ,kal, Rank() over(order    by point desc) as 'ranking' from karbar order by point desc";  
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);  

   SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   adapt.Fill(ds);
   cnt=ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
   PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
   pds.AllowPaging=true;
   pds.DataSource=ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   pds.PageSize=5;
   pds.CurrentPageIndex=counter;
   int vcnt=cnt/pds.PageSize;
   rptList.DataSource = pds;  
   rptList.DataBind();
```

}

Comment: I think the issue is within your webmethod. Do you have the whole exception?

Comment: hi.problem is static keword.and its exception:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 



Line 67:        rptList.DataSource = pds;  
Line 68:   rptList.DataBind(); 
Line 69:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why you get exception?

My guess would be, because APS.NET disposes the DataSet (not seen here) after each request, while you are trying to page results from the previous request. If you make a DataSet *static* (it's a big no-no in ASP.NET) then it is kept in the memory and is also shared between all the requests.

### How to fix this?

You are using incorrect data access pattern. Datasets are really fat bad boys and practically should not be used with ASP.NET.

- Get rid of the DataSet completely. Do not use static objects, when you get some traffic to your application you will see real weird bugs.
- Use something more lightweight, like `List<Record>` and populate it with `DataReader`.
- Use *database* paging, instead of *in-memory* paging. Never ask database server to bring all the data, or else your app will go down (when you get some traffic and database becomes larger).
- Consider using ORM (like NHibernate or EF), it will do a lot of magic for you.

Answer (score 0):

1st of all web methods has to be static as we call them directly without creating any object.
And 2nd thing is that we cannot access any server side controls directly in web method.

Here you can get the data source in client side and bind it with the repeater in client side.

```
success: function (ret) {

            // here get the datasource as "ret".
            // bind the repeater with the data source manually.
     }
```

OR

Put your controls inside update panel then, you dont need any client side databnind, not you need any ajax call in jQuery.

Comment: thanks. iknow that i had to use static keyword. do you can say me how i bind datasource in client side?and how pass the object of datasource?

Comment: There is no direct method. You have to do it manually in client side. For example if you need to bind grid view in client side, we know that grid view is rendered as table, so we can run a loop and do the binding stuff for each row.
Similarly for repeater you have to find how it is rendered in client side(html equivalent of repeater control). Then get the data source either as a list or as a table in client and bind the respective controls with respective value.

Comment: im so sorry that i get your time but do you have any code for this operation?

Comment: Without knowing repeater content and datasource, the client side bind function cant be written. If you are having trouble in this then use update panel directly, it will make your life easy.

Comment: Also binding these controls in client side is not a good idea, as you might need some validation or might want to customize your datasource's data before showing them in repeater. So directly bind the repeater in click event handler of your button.

Comment: Webmethods does not have to be static, the framework instatiates the class.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes we can define web methods as non static. But if we will do so, this functions can not be called in ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

The `rptList` member is null, create a new rptList before you try to use it